# Quero criar uma variável com o nome dinâmico com javascript

Tags: javascript, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Para exemplificar melhor, eu tenho um for, e quero que para cada vez que rodar o laço, se crie uma variável com o `NOME` dela mais o índice do for ex:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 var "variavel+i" = i
 console.log("variavel+i")
}
```

Nesse caso o laço criaria as variáveis da seguinte forma:

```
var variavel0

var variavel1

var variavel2
```

E assim por diante. Alem de imprimir no console os valores `0,1,2 ...`

Comment: Você pode criar uma array e inserir os valores dentro da array, não? É exatamente pra isso que elas servem.

Comment: Acho que você está prestes a fazer alguma gambiarra desnecessária. Uma forma de fazer uma variável global seria com `window["variavel" + i]`, mas é completamente desnecessário.

Comment: `variavel[i] = i;` Simples assim

Comment: Se o seu problema vai bem além disso seria legal você explicá-lo. Assim podemos oferecer soluções úteis.

Comment: E por que não pode usar *array* se esta é a solução adequada?

Comment: @Maniero injusto - o AP foi bem claro em sua pergunta de como criar uma série de variáveis com nomes diferentes sem ter que declarar uma a uma (dinamicamente) - ele não perguntou sobre arrays

Comment: @Sorack o AP foi bem claro no que ele precisa

Comment: @Blogueira acho que nessa parte `[EDIT] -- Pessoal, não posso usar Array nesse caso. O código que coloquei é apenas um exemplo para facilitar o entendimento, meu problema vai bem além disso.` mostra bem que isso não é o que ele precisa, ou seja, não está claro.

Comment: @Blogueira só resta saber se o escopo que ele precisa que gere isso é global ou não. Ai talvez sim poderemos reabrir a pergunta de modo que seja proveitoso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho irrelevante - a maioria das soluções para um problema possuem suas limitações - e se esse fosse o motivo para manter a pergunta fechada, imagino que quem fechou teria pedido esse esclarecimento ao invés de fechar

Comment: @Blogueira isso é algo já discutido a muito tempo, quem tem experiencia sabe os problemas como perguntas cameleão ou problema X & Y que pode causar, como eu disse, se especificar a parte do escopo (que em JavaScript é muito importante) então blz, tá boa para reabrir, se reabrir como esta possivelmente (não é uma afirmação que vá ocorrer, mas "pode") poderá ocorrer alguns problemas. Fechamento não é banimento, não deletar para sempre e a ferramenta tem o seu propósito. No Meta tem bastante link sobre o assunto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exatamente. E eu fui o primeiro a votar pelo fechamento justamente por conta do `EDIT` do AP que deixa claro que esse não é o problema dele e por isso ele queria outra solução. "Preciso somar A+B, mas não posso fazer isso fazendo a soma porque não vai resolver o meu problema". Não tem muito como ajudar e acaba só gerando ruído.

Comment: Eduardo Roberto Ferreira, note que o fechamento não é "repúdio" à sua questão, simplesmente ficou uma dúvida se o problema é só a "variável variável" ou tem mais requisitos que vc não disse, e essa "pausa" é pra esclarecer antes que apareça mais uma série de respostas que não resolve. Se puder se manifestar, pode ser que consigamos ajudar tanto com a solução quanto com a edição da pergunta.

Comment: Eduardo, isso não parece fazer sentido. Um array resolveria o problema, ou uma outra estrutura de dados. A escolha certa da *estrutura de dados* que vai usar é o que vai determinar o sucesso da solução. Ainda mais que você nem contextualizou na pergunta o problema que te levou a pensar dessa forma, criar as variáveis dessa maneira, e mesmo que tenha esse não é o caminho, pode te atrapalhar no futuro. E você tem que considerar o escopo da variável também e certamente não é possível fazer isso em JavaScript, pelo menos não da forma que você imagina.

Comment: Está certo, creio que fui claro que não posso utilizar Array... mas OK... 
Se julga que "falta detalhes", ok...
Meu problema envolve interoperabilidade semântica, utilizo uma linguagem fechada, e estou integrando uma pagina com JavaScript com esse sistema "fechado". 
Resolvi o problema com o "eval()" que alguem postou ontem, mas hoje quando entrei para marcar como resposta não encontrei mais.

Comment: Não poderia usar Array porque não consigo acessar um objeto array "do outro lado, com a outra linguagem"...
enfim.... ainda acho que informei corretamente o meu problema, e que fui claro à não poder utilizar Array.....
Não é "quero somar a+b mas nao posso fazer a soma"
É: "Quero criar variaveis de uma forma dinamica, e não posso utilizar Array"
Sobre o escopo: Não precisa ser global.

Comment: a resposta usando eval() é a da @devgirl - ela mudou para window[] depois que comentaram que "não precisava", e que, pelo visto "dá no mesmo" - eu, particularmente, depois de conhecer, prefiro o eval()

Comment: e por mais que eu saiba que são pessoas ajudando pessoas nesse site, acho que a sua razão para não poder usar array não diz respeito a ninguém - sua pergunta foi clara sem essa informação, e servirá para outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida no site (eu, por exemplo, gostei de aprender sobre isso) - eu removeria as suas edições, que foi o motivo que alguns deram para marcar sua pergunta como "não clara", e deixaria: "como faz x?" (a primeira versão postada) e pronto - não existe nada mais claro que isso

Comment: Também acho isso @Blogueira...
Coloquei o edit apenas pq todo mundo estava falando para usar Array...
Mas enfim.... Esse problema só tive aqui, no stackoverflow gringo o pessoal respondeu sem ficar fazendo indagações e querendo entender a síntese real do problema.
Creio q tanto a pergunta, quanto a resposta prática ajuda quem consultar a pergunta.....
Para explicar meu problema envolveria regras de negócio bem especificas que dificilmente seria aproveitadas em outro lugar.....
Enfim... coloquei, apesar de generico, tudo de forma bem resumida, mas nao menos claro ou prático.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Já que você não pode usar array:

```js
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){

      window["variavel"+i] = i;

      console.log(window["variavel"+i])
    }
```